# How to get users id after filter and map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an Object with the name and user id for each service, I want the object to look like this:

```
const object = {
    name: Netflix, user: (user id who pays max price for this provider)
    name: Comcast, user: (same)
    name: Verizon, user: (same)
}
```

I have tried changing the object property in the map return but it's not working, also I already have the object half done I mean with the names of the providers now I need the other key,value pair

```
const services = [
     { userid: 1, providerId: 1, amount: 250000 },
     { userid: 4, providerId: 3, amount: 280900 },
     { userid: 6, providerId: 3, amount: 31000 },
     { userid: 2, providerId: 2, amount: 58600 },
     { userid: 3, providerId: 1, amount: 13000 },
     { userid: 5, providerId: 2, amount: 5000 },
     { userid: 3, providerId: 3, amount: 59900 },
     { userid: 6, providerId: 3, amount: 9500 }
]

const providers = [
    { id: 1, name: Netflix },
    { id: 2, name: Comcast },
    { id: 3, name: Verizon }
]
```

This is my function

```
function getUserId(providerId) {
    return services.filter(function(obj) {
        if (obj.providerId == providerId)
            return obj.providerId;
    }).map(function(obj) { return obj.amount });
}

function getMaxUserId(providerId) {
    return Math.max(...getUserId(providerId));
}

providers.forEach(prov => {
    object[prov.name] = getUserId(prov.id);
})
```

as you can see first I filter the entire array looking for the providers with certain providerId then I create a new array with map function filled with all the 'amounts' for that particular provider and last I search for the max amount of that array, this all works fine it return the right max amount for each provider BUT I also want to get the user id who's paying the most for each provider

actually I'm getting my object like this:

```
[
   {name: Netflix, user: 250000},
   {name: Comcast, user: 58600},
   {name: Verizon, user: 280900}
]
```

and I need this:

```
[
   {name: Netflix, user: 1},
   {name: Comcast, user: 2},
   {name: Verizon, user: 4}
]
```

Comment: Your desired output in the first code sample is not possible. Objects can't have duplicate keys. Editing the question to fix that will make this a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @MarkMeyer the object he's talking about is actually an array, so it's not an issue.  What is an issue is the `accounts` object has not been provided in the question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @Mark Meyer the code I provided kinda works is just that instead the user id paying the max is returning the max ammount

Comment: @Tibrogargan I edited the code it wasn't accounts it supposed to be services array sorry

Comment: Ok, but it's still not clear where your "user" is coming from.  The assumption most people would make for something called `services` is that the `id` is the unique identifier of a service.  Not seeing anything in your question that could reasonably identify a user.

Comment: Hi, Noderjs! Sorry to barge in - regardless of reference issues, just reference `obj.id` instead of the `obj.ammount` - as far as I understand your goal, your `getUserId()` function maps `ammount` to output `Array` (I suppose `id` key in `services` elements references user id, right?)

Comment: @Tibrogargan haha thanks for the clarification I edited the code again hope you can help me now

Comment: @OlegValter I did but is giving incorrect values don't know why that's my problem >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And, as a third possible solution to your problem (following up on my comment), you can use something like this (you can modify the object however you deem more to your liking, but I would suggest getting rid of `name` and `user` keys altogether):

```
const object = {};

function getUserId(providerId) {
    return services.filter(function(obj) {
        if (obj.providerId == providerId)
            return obj.providerId;
    }).map(function(obj) { return obj });
}

function getMaxUserId(output) {
    let amm = output.map( (o) => { return o.amount; } );
    let idx = amm.indexOf(Math.max(...amm));
    return output[idx].userid;
}

providers.forEach(prov => {
    object[prov.name] = getMaxUserId(getUserId(prov.id));
})

console.log(object)
```

The output in your case using this solution will look like this:

```
Object { Netflix: 1, Comcast: 2, Verizon: 4 }
```

Ofc, with a small tweak you will be able to return an `Array` with objects as originally intended (don't forget to assign `object` to `[]` instead):

```
providers.forEach(prov => {
  object.push( {name:prov.name,user:getMaxUserId(getUserId(prov.id))} )
})
```

In the latter case the output will look like this:

```
Array [Object { name: "Netflix", user: 1 }, Object { name: "Comcast", user: 2 }, Object { name: "Verizon", user: 4 }]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also `sort` your services on the `amount`. Then you can **group** them by the `providerId` and finally map over the providers to get the output you want:

```js
const services = [ { id: 1, providerId: 1, amount: 250000 }, { id: 4, providerId: 3, amount: 280900 }, { id: 6, providerId: 3, amount: 31000 }, { id: 2, providerId: 2, amount: 58600 }, { id: 3, providerId: 1, amount: 13000 }, { id: 5, providerId: 2, amount: 5000 }, { id: 3, providerId: 3, amount: 59900 }, { id: 6, providerId: 3, amount: 9500 } ]
const providers = [ { id: 1, name: 'Netflix' }, { id: 2, name: 'Comcast' }, { id: 3, name: 'Verizon' } ] 

let grouped = services
  .sort((a,b) => b.amount - a.amount)  // sort `desc`
  .reduce((r,c) => ((r[c.providerId] = r[c.providerId] || []).push(c), r), {})
 
let result = providers.map(p => ({name: p.name, user: grouped[p.id][0].id}))

console.log(result)
```

You could also skip the `sort` above and check the `amount` and based on that either `push` or `unshift`:

```js
const services = [ { id: 1, providerId: 1, amount: 250000 }, { id: 4, providerId: 3, amount: 280900 }, { id: 6, providerId: 3, amount: 31000 }, { id: 2, providerId: 2, amount: 58600 }, { id: 3, providerId: 1, amount: 13000 }, { id: 5, providerId: 2, amount: 5000 }, { id: 3, providerId: 3, amount: 59900 }, { id: 6, providerId: 3, amount: 9500 } ]
const providers = [ { id: 1, name: 'Netflix' }, { id: 2, name: 'Comcast' }, { id: 3, name: 'Verizon' } ] 

let groupedById = services.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
  let k = cur.providerId
  acc[k] = acc[k] || []
  if(acc[k][0] && acc[k][0].amount > cur.amount) acc[k].push(cur)
  else acc[k].unshift(cur)
  return acc
}, {})

let result = providers.map(({name, id}) => ({name, user: groupedById[id][0].id}))

console.log(result)
```

This way you only have one `Array.reduce` and one `Array.map` which will be `more performant` than your original version which has `forEach`, `filter` and `map`.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally we'd have argmax in JS. But for now, normal iteration looks nicer. Note the rarely-seen `==` because JS turns the dictionary keys into strings:

```
var maxes = {};
services.forEach(item => {
    if(!maxes[item.providerId] || maxes[item.providerId] < item.amount[0]) {
        maxes[item.providerId] = [item.amount, item.id];
    }
});
function providerById(id) {
    return providers.filter(p => p.id == key)[0].name;
}
console.log(Object.keys(maxes).map(key => {
    return { name: providerById(key), user: maxes[key][1] };
}));
```